# get elements that is in viewport

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, viewport

What I wanted to do is to get the visible elements within viewport with respect to its parent container. Checking is triggered via and animated scrolling of its parent.

I have found some codes from here, functions that can check if the element is in viewport but somehow I could not get it right.

here's the current function that checks if it's in viewport or not.

```
function  checkInView(elem,partial)
{
var container = $("#timeline_wrapper");
var contHeight = container.height();
var contTop = container.scrollTop();
var contBottom = contTop + contHeight ;

var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top - container.offset().top;
var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

var isTotal = (elemTop >= 0 && elemBottom <=contHeight);
var isPart = ((elemTop < 0 && elemBottom > 0 ) || (elemTop > 0 && elemTop <= container.height())) && partial ;

return  isTotal  || isPart ;
}
```

and here's a fiddle of the complete set that I'm trying to make : http://jsfiddle.net/j3toxicat3d/zrnCU/

Comment: You might try this plugin, or look at its source to get an idea: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

Comment: the function above really does the trick, but when used against multiple objects it seems something is wrong. that's what im trying to fix.